# SQL Server Joining with between condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please check my table first. My first table is called `DinasHoHeader`:

```
    Kode    Desc    startdate   enddate
      1     Desc 1  2016-11-08  2016-11-08
      2     Desc 2  2016-11-16  2016-11-16
```

and the second table is  called `CutOff`

```
CutOffCode         Month    Year       from          to
CO-2016-10-16-15    10      2016    2016-09-16  2016-10-15
CO-2016-11-16-15    11      2016    2016-10-16  2016-11-15
CO-2016-12-16-15    12      2016    2016-11-16  2016-12-15
```

I want to join the two. Here is what I try

```
SELECT a.*, b.CutOffCode 
FROM DinasHoHeader a
LEFT JOIN CutOff b ON b.[From] BETWEEN a.[startdate] AND a.enddate  
                   AND b.[to] BETWEEN a.[startdate] AND a.enddate
```

But with my query I can't get the `CutOffCode`.

So my question is: how to join those two tables so I can get the `cutoffcode`?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should explain what logic you want to implement.  What are the desired results and how are they calculated?

Comment: Is there any relation between these two table ? join on dates will not give you exact result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your logic is backwards:

```
select dhh.*, co.CutOffCode
from DinasHoHeader dhh left join
     CutOff co
     on dhh.[startdate] between co.[From] and co.[to] and
        dhh.[enddate] between co.[From] and co.[to];
```

This should at least have some matches.